# Some Syntax Error - Can't figure out where

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-06550

Here is the script that i wrote and it has weird syntax error at EXCEPTION block. If i remove exception block the script compiles properly. but no sooner i write it back it gives me error

```
Error(58,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

Here is the script

```
LOOP
  BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT check_point;

    EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (cursor_handle) = 0;
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 1,  cc , col_err, actual_len);
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 2,  di, col_err, actual_len);

    IF INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0 THEN
      cc := Trim (cc);
      cc := Upper(cc);
      cc := substr(cc,4,2);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET cc = :v1 WHERE di = :v2' 
        USING cc, di;

      if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
        inserts := inserts + 1;
        counter := counter + 1;
        IF counter > 500 THEN
          counter := 0;
          COMMIT;
        END IF;
      END IF;

      EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
          dups := dups+1;
          ROLLBACK TO check_point;
        WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
          valerr := valerr +1;
          ROLLBACK TO check_point;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errno: ' || TO_CHAR(SQLCODE) || ' Msg: ' || SQLERRM);
          otherexc := otherexc +1;
        IF otherexc > 50 THEN 
          EXIT;
        END IF;
        ROLLBACK TO check_point;              
    END IF;
  END;
END LOOP;
```

I know its very annoying to ask such kind a question but i am unable to figure out what error is that. I am lehman at Pl/SQL.

Comment: Okay, I guess i figured it out. The Exception Block has to be the last block in the loop. I have this **IF INSTR** statment and EXCEPTION block was in that IF statement. So i ended the IF statement right before the beginning of exception block and the error is gone. Would someone mind explaining this concept?

Comment: The `EXCEPTION` has to be the last part of the block, but if you only want it to apply to the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` then you can but that inside its own `BEGIN`/`END` block *inside* the `IF INSTR ... END IF` part. That probably isn't what you want, though.

Comment: Thanks, How can i accept your comment as an answer :)

Comment: I'd have to convert it, and since Justin has shown the principle in his second example and explained it more thoroughly in a comment, it's probably not worth it *8-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears to be that your EXCEPTION clause is inside the `IF INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0` IF statements but you appear to want to match the EXCEPTION to the BEGIN statement at the top of your loop.  I believe that you want to move the END IF; for the `IF INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0` before the EXCEPTION as I do here

```
LOOP
  BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT check_point;

    EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (cursor_handle) = 0;
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 1,  cc , col_err, actual_len);
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 2,  di, col_err, actual_len);

    IF INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0 THEN
      cc := Trim (cc);
      cc := Upper(cc);
      cc := substr(cc,4,2);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET cc = :v1 WHERE di = :v2' 
        USING cc, di;

      if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
        inserts := inserts + 1;
        counter := counter + 1;
        IF counter > 500 THEN
          counter := 0;
          COMMIT;
        END IF; -- IF counter > 500
      END IF; -- IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
    END IF; -- INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0


  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      dups := dups+1;
      ROLLBACK TO check_point;
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
      valerr := valerr +1;
      ROLLBACK TO check_point;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errno: ' || TO_CHAR(SQLCODE) || ' Msg: ' || SQLERRM);
      otherexc := otherexc +1;
      IF otherexc > 50 THEN 
        EXIT;
      END IF;
      ROLLBACK TO check_point;              
  END;
END LOOP;
```

That being said, however, I would probably rewrite the code a bit.  Committing every 500 rows is almost certainly an error.  I'm very dubious of your WHEN OTHERS exception handler-- I would really think that you'd want to at least write the error to a table or populate a collection of errors rather than writing to the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer that may or may not ever be displayed.

```
LOOP
  SAVEPOINT check_point;

  EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (cursor_handle) = 0;
  DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 1,  cc , col_err, actual_len);
  DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (cursor_handle, 2,  di, col_err, actual_len);

  IF INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0 THEN
    cc := Trim (cc);
    cc := Upper(cc);
    cc := substr(cc,4,2);

    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE  ' || dest || ' SET cc = :v1 WHERE di = :v2' 
        USING cc, di;

      if SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
        inserts := inserts + 1;
      END IF; 
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        dups := dups+1;
        ROLLBACK TO check_point;
      WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        valerr := valerr +1;
        ROLLBACK TO check_point;
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('errno: ' || TO_CHAR(SQLCODE) || ' Msg: ' || SQLERRM);
        otherexc := otherexc +1;
        IF otherexc > 50 THEN 
          EXIT;
        END IF;
        ROLLBACK TO check_point;              
    END;

  END IF; -- INSTR (cc, '_') <> 0
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I figured that out already but my question still stands there that how to match that exceoption clause for "Execute immediate" or for the "BEGIN" statement?

Comment: An EXCEPTION clause has to match a BEGIN (and an END).  A BEGIN and END form a complete PL/SQL block (with or without an EXCEPTION).  A PL/SQL block cannot overlap with another construct-- if you start an IF block after the BEGIN, the EXCEPTION has to come after the END IF.  In the second version of the block, putting the BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END more closely together around the UPDATE makes it a bit clearer what is going on.